# Adding HTML Button to Dynamics CRM 2016 Form

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm

What I'm attempting to do is add an HTML button that will trigger as really simple javascript function. 
Essentially onclick, I want to see if a field contains a value of 0.00 - if so remove that value. Or, if the field does not contain data, add in the value of 0.00 so it should alternate between those two values.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="ReCalc">Re-Calculate Balance</button>
      <script>
      function ReCalc() {
        var BalanceWriteOff = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("jucy_balancewriteoff").getValue();
        if ((BalanceWriteOff) ==null)
          Xrm.Page.getAttribute("balancewriteoff").setValue("0");
          Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
        if ((BalanceWriteOff) =="0")
          Xrm.Page.getAttribute("jucy_balancewriteoff").setValue(null);
          Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
            return;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I try to run this on the form where the HTML element has been placed. Nothing is happening. I've thrown in some break points at the var and both if statements and I'm not getting a break when I'm triggering the onclick event.

I'm kind of stumped here. If anyone has any insights for me that would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access CRM form fields from an HTML web resource, add this script to the HTML:

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and prepend "parent" to the Xrm.Page object:

```
parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("jucy_balancewriteoff").getValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Oops! In your `onclick` attribute you forgot to invoke the method.

To fix this, simply change `onclick="ReCalc"` to `onclick="ReCalc()"`.

Here's a code pen to show you it works now - https://codepen.io/trentrand/pen/Jyomgr

Comment: Absolutely. If you felt my answer solved the core problem described in your original post, please mark it as accepted so others in the future may refer to it as the solution.